# How to get the count field in messageReaction collection discord.js

Tags: javascript, collections, count, discord.js

I am fetching a message and wanting to get the count of how many reactions are on it. I am able to get the whole collection, but I want to strip out the "count" field. How can I achieve getting that number stripped from the attached pictures collection map?

```
        message.client.channels.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
        channel.messages.fetch(messageID).then(message => {
            const cache = message.reactions.cache;
            console.log(cache);
        })
    })
```

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmNDg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing is for sure.
The object you have right now (`cache`) is not a message reaction, it is an instance of a Collection.
The key is a string/Snowflake, the value is a MessageReaction. So, if you wanted to get a specific reaction count, get the Reaction object by using `Collection#get`, then use `MessageReaction#count`.

However, if you are looking for the total reactions of the message, I suggest you map the values of the Collection to a number and then reduce that array to a number.

Comment: okay, I'm not quite sure how to write that. Any help on that? I am looking to get total reactions of the message...